# Would radio telescope located anywhere within a 100 light year radius detect our radio emissions?

Tags: radio-astronomy, radio-telescope

If there was a radio telescope, as sophisticated as our best radio telescopes within a 100 light year radius from earth.

AND if its sole purpose was search for signs of artificial/intelligent radio transmissions like our SETI program.

What chance would such radio telescope have of detecting our radio emissions regardless of its three dimensional location relative to earth and how would that chance change the further it is from us?

Comment: A subset of https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8146/how-far-away-could-we-detect-that-earth-has-life

Comment: See also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8423/how-should-exoplanet-discoveries-affect-seti/8424#8424 and https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18059/can-seti-certify-whether-or-not-proxima-b-is-inhabited-by-beings-using-electroma/18064#18064

Comment: @RobJeffries Thanks, did not see that one. However, I think this one is different enough and more specific and is therefore not a duplicate. Detecting life could also mean analyzing the atmosphere of a planet as we are currently attempting to do.

Comment: Your answer here https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/18064/28782, pretty much answers my question...

Comment: by power signal degradation type logarithmic, and lobed  comunication phase , maybe not, because is like to you see blank sheets